# Similar to Login using facebook

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We have around 10 websites. I have been asked to create a functionality similar to Login using Facebook which now a days all websites are using, so that we do not need to register with them. We can use facebook credantials.

So out of our 10 websites we have 1 main website e.g. called  abc.com(e-commerece website running on MAGENTO) . I want to put a button on other 9 websites login page called login using abc.com

how could I do that. I have checked on OAuth and MAGENTO's REST OAuth. Because I'm not that experienced so would like to have some ideas or anything else you have used. What would be the right way of doing that?

Comment: Maybe set up one site as an OpenID provider and the other sites just use that provider as their authentication?  http://openid.net/

Comment: How are the other websites connected, sub domains of abc or something else?

Comment: all websites are separate lying on different servers.

Comment: I'm not sure of how you would implement this, why not have all of the stores point to the same database->table to login? It should be as simple as changing a few files. I imagine the login process uses something such as getStore then getLogin, find the value getStore should be returning for abc.com and change the getStore value. You would just be using one user table to manage all of your stores. It could also be useful to cut down on space, as users would not have multiple entries from the separate sites.

Comment: Also, this page is essentially asking your question: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/202444/

Comment: Nathan but I think that is not the right way of doing it. It's kind of a insecure too because it requires to open ports on my db server to run queries directly from other servers. I think OpenID is the right way of doing this as suggested by David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openID suggested by David in comments

Answer (score 0):

Use the below extension to login through Facebook

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebookfreebelvg-4448.html

Comment: I am not looking for extension but a similar functionality using my own main company site instead of facebook.